# Sending Scheduled email in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, scheduled-tasks

I'm working on a WordPress website that accepts a schedule for a service. After 6 months of this said service, i want to send a notice of service due , if it's still unpaid. The notice is send via email. I'm stuck on how to implement the task scheduler for sending the notice via email. Any idea on how to implement this?

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59426/sending-out-scheduled-emails
I found this and gave me a little idea. More detailed idea than this would help a lot. I'm using windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

On *nix systems you have to use cron jobs. Cron jobs will simply execute your script every time depending on configuration. You can configure cron to be executed every hour, every day, every year, every 6 month etc.

If you are sending payment notification to users every month (I mean payment should be made every month) you have to configure cron to be executed everymonth. In your script you should select users who do not pay for service 6 months (just subtracting 6 months from now and comparing last payment time from db) and send them emails.

You can find related information on these links:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Cron+Jobs

Comment: Do you use Windows on server or on your machine?

Comment: on my machine. sorry for that.